# Android surfaceview, services to start background video recording

Tags: android

When i used Surface view with services to start background video recording in my android application then it's capturing video. When i try to open that video then the video is force closing. For this i wrote code like this. And when i run this application on my Sony mobile then call receiving functionality is not working. If any one have an idea could you please share with me.

```
public class VideoRecorderService extends Service implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private Camera camera = null;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

      /*  // Start foreground service to avoid unexpected kill
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Background Video Recorder")
            .setContentText("")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .build();
        startForeground(1234, notification);*/

        // Create new SurfaceView, set its size to 1x1, move it to the top left corner and set this service as a callback
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            1, 1,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

    }

    // Method called right after Surface created (initializing and starting MediaRecorder)
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        camera = Camera.open();
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        camera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        //mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240); 

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+
                DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime())+
                ".mp4"
        );

        try { mediaRecorder.prepare(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        mediaRecorder.start();

    }

    // Stop recording and remove SurfaceView
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();

        camera.lock();
        camera.release();

        windowManager.removeView(surfaceView);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }

}
```

and below are the error logs i am getting when i run my application:

```
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291): java.lang.IllegalStateException
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at com.android.camerarecorder.VideoRecorderService.surfaceCreated(VideoRecorderService.java:86)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:553)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1710)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2539)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-06 17:42:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(8291):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you  managed to solve this?

Comment: Got the solution?