# How to create MACRO'S in android

Tags: android, macros, bluetooth, automation, video-capture

I want to create macro app in Android, which will help user to set the requirement to do schduled tasks for the user like scheduled video recording like (camstudio in windows OS),GPS,Bluetooth,Camera control. I know have to ROOT the device to do these things..

```
Advance Features :    
• Shake the device to upload the last photo to Facebook.    
• Turn on Wi-fi or Data connection when you launch a particular app (and off again when closed).
• Respond to an incoming SMS by sending your current location.    
• Toggle the power button to tell you the time (e.g. when its in your pocket).    
• Use NFC tags to configure the device (turn on bluetooth, set volume etc).
```

Actually I have code for doing all the things except **scheduled video recording**.

Can you guys help me in that part **only**..

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have to Root the device to have these features. What you need is a [Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) which implements various listeners such as :

1. SensorListener to  [detect shaking of device](http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-shake-detection-listener).
2. [BroadcastReceiver to fire when SMSs are received.](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87)
3. Or [Handle WiFi.](http://androidtutorialspoint.blogspot.sg/2013/10/wifimanager-provides-primary-api-for.html)

Edit 1 :

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {
        private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
        private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
        private static Camera mServiceCamera;
        private boolean mRecordingStatus;
        private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            mRecordingStatus = false;
            //mServiceCamera = CameraRecorder.mCamera;
            mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
            mSurfaceView = CameraRecorder.mSurfaceView;
            mSurfaceHolder = CameraRecorder.mSurfaceHolder;

            super.onCreate();
            if (mRecordingStatus == false)
                startRecording();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            stopRecording();
            mRecordingStatus = false;

            super.onDestroy();
        }   

        public boolean startRecording(){
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
                Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
                mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
                Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

                final List<Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
                Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width 
                            + " height = " + mPreviewSize.height);
                p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
                p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
                mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

                try {
                    mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                    mServiceCamera.startPreview();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mServiceCamera.unlock();

                mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
                mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
                mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
                mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/video.mp4");
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
                mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

                mMediaRecorder.prepare();
                mMediaRecorder.start(); 

                mRecordingStatus = true;

                return true;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void stopRecording() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                mServiceCamera.reconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();

            mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
            mMediaRecorder.release();

            mServiceCamera.release();
            mServiceCamera = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then what about 'scheduled video recording'?

Comment: automatically start video recording at a scheduled time?

Comment: Please read out my question once again .... Actually I have code for doing all the things except scheduled video recording.

Comment: Check out Edit 1. Service which records the video. To schedule the execution of the service, use AlarmManager.

Comment: I havent included C++ code anywhere. That's pure Java :)

Comment: I wanted to use NDK ...something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328751/android-macro-suddenly-not-defined

Comment: Didnt this question have a +50 bounty. Never got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with  [SpotRecorder](https://github.com/tobykurien/SpotReport/tree/master/SpotRecorder) (house4hack) code which contains a activity to start RecorderService service in background (we need to make view so that it will not be visible. this should be done in the service )

We can use the AlarmManager for setting the alarm of particular time,when alarm manger fires that time by using intent start your service again, same methode can be used for stopping your app.

no sure, but you can try to consider using [WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html) and call it from Service.
look at this failed attempt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576139/android-surfaceview-services-to-start-background-video-recording).